# Updating Column Names from Excel in Combobox for Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter

**Goal:** 
I am trying to have the script look through a directory named 'data' that is in the working directory of the script for excel workbooks. The script will then have a options menu of the different workbooks to choose from which will then give a selection of column names to choose from in a combo box above.

**Results:**
I was able to get it to read the default excel workbook upon start up but when I choose a different workbook the combo box does not update the column names.

I've tried to incorporate some sort of update function but I keep having trouble even running it because one or more things don't really line up. I am still new to python and tkinter so I would like some advice and suggestions to solve this problem.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd


def _quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()


root = Tk()
root.title('BLURG')
root.geometry("1280x720")

path = os.chdir('Data')
filenames = os.listdir(path)
data_as_list = []
for filename in filenames:
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx') or filename.endswith('.xls'):
        data_as_list.append(filename)

clicked = StringVar()
options = data_as_list
clicked.set(options[0])
drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options)
drop.pack(side="right")

data = pd.read_excel(clicked.get())
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
col_name = list(df.columns)
labelx = tkinter.Label(root, text="x-axis: ")
combox = ttk.Combobox(root, values=col_name)

labelx.pack(side="top")
combox.pack(side="top")

button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your code from line `data=pd.read_excel(...)` to `col_name = list(df.columns)` should be inserted in your **Update** function, along with a `combox['values'] = col_name`

Comment: Also add a command to your `OptionMenu` to register the updates

Comment: I tried your suggestion but running into errors of either undefined combox or col_name.

Comment: Oh, never mind I got it. I added a postcommand with the update funtion in the combobox and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using an update function with a postcommand fixed the problem.

```
...
def update_list():
    data = pd.read_excel(clicked.get())
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    col_name = list(df.columns)
    combox['values'] = col_name


labelx = tkinter.Label(root, text="x-axis: ")
combox = ttk.Combobox(root, postcommand=update_list)
...
```